# Text in table in blog post Stack Overflow Badge Feedback is hard to read in dark mode

Tags: bug, blog, accessibility, dark-mode

I was reading the blog article [Stack Overflow Badge Feedback](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/07/12/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/).

The text in the second column of the table is tough to read in dark mode because of the grey background colour.

[image: badge names in grey text on slightly lighter grey background]

Please fix the background colour so that it is easy to read.

This is how the table looks like in non-dark mode:

[image: text is black instead]