# The Overflow's content is difficult to read in dark mode

Tags: bug, status-declined, blog, dark-mode, the-overflow

The [most recent "The Overflow" edition](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/05/27/the-overflow-127-what-we-learned-from-ddos-attacks/) is very difficult to read in dark mode. Here's a screenshot to showcase what I mean:

[image: The Overflow's content in dark mode - Visually very difficult to read.]

The new format looks great, it's just that the content isn't responsive to dark mode's color inversion.

In light mode, this [looks perfectly fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMdNT.png).

Could this be fixed?

Comment: Looks broken to me in light mode too. CSS issues maybe?

Comment: It looks like the entire thing is just extracted from the email, which uses all inline CSS to make it display more consistently across email clients (and doesn't support dark mode). But that makes it look terrible when inserted into a web page where other styles can get applied to it.

Comment: How do I change the site to dark mode?  I have my computer in dark mode but this site is still in light mode.

Comment: @AndersGustafson Click the second button from the right in the top-right corner of the blog. ([screenshot with red circle](https://i.imgur.com/kxDtZH2.png))

Comment: @AndersGustafson dark mode is currently only available on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I checked in with the Marketing team. This is the only article that was impacted due to some changes on their backend and the system not saving work in between the switch. This shouldn't be impacting any other articles in dark mode. Unfortunately, they don't currently have the bandwidth to fix this one outlier so I've updated this to status-declined. If you do notice the issue in future posts please let us know and I'll bring it to their attention.

Comment: Rosie, can you please take a look at this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374231?

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime one can use Chrome's dark mode on desktop:

[image]

Or Opera's dark mode on Android:

[image]

Comment: Heh, yeah Chrome's innate dark mode makes it look pretty good.